# How can I drop specific columns with Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to work with a CSV data set, specifically one from AirQualityUCI. I'm using Pandas and need to drop certain columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/air/AirQualityUCI.csv") 
print(df.columns)
```

yields

```
Index(['Date;Time;CO(GT);PT08.S1(CO);NMHC(GT);C6H6(GT);PT08.S2(NMHC);NOx(GT);PT08.S3(NOx);NO2(GT);PT08.S4(NO2);PT08.S5(O3);T;RH;AH;;'], dtype='object')
```

just to illustrate dropping a single column, the fourth,  gives the error
KeyError: "['PT08.S1(CO)'] not found in axis"  and  also with other and multiple keys, also using integers.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the csv do

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/air/AirQualityUCI.csv", sep=';')
```

Then you can `drop` it

```
df = df.drop('PT08.S1(CO)',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
print(df.columns)
```

yields

```
Index(['Date;Time;...;RH;AH;;'], dtype='object')
```

we know that the data is being interpreted as a `panda.Index` object instead of a list.

A [panda.Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) object is an "Immutable sequence used for indexing and alignment. The basic object storing axis labels for all pandas objects."

So in order to perform any list operations, you need to convert the Index object to a list by calling the `.toList()` function.

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/air/AirQualityUCI.csv").toList() # convert to a list
df = df.drop('PT08.S1(CO)') # drop the column 'PT08.S1(C0)'
```